# is it okay for a paper to be in conference proceedings but not on IEEE Xplore?

Tags: publications, conference, ieee, indexing

A conference says on its call for papers website that: "papers will be part of the Conference Proceedings (if the authors wish to do so), but they will not be uploaded to IEEE Xplore." -- What does this mean exactly? If I agree for it to be in the proceedings then will I be able to find it using the ISBN of the conference? Will it have a DOI (I highly doubt, but still wanted to know)?

Thank you in advance. I appreciate your time and consideration.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask someone with the conference?  Seems specific to them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because it's impossible for us to say in which form the organizers of said conference will (or will not) publish their proceedings.

Comment: Is it a conference with maybe IEEE Technical sponsorship but not an IEEE endorsed and sponsored conference?